# How can I copy and paste files within the File Explorer using ftp?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ftp, files-folders

The Windows File Explorer lets me define a folder as a ftp location and I'm able to copy files into and out of the folders, but I'm not able to move files within the folder.

e.g. If I want to move a file in the ftp folder into another ftp folder on the same server or sub folder. I have to copy the file to my desktop and then from there, copy it to the target folder. Instead of just using drag and drop like a normal folder.

Is there a way to fix that without relying on a third party ftp client?

[image]

Comment: Yes, right click and "cut" then paste to new folder.

Comment: @Petepf It does not have an option for cut, only copy. If I copy the file with that option. The paste stays grayed out. Added an image.

Comment: Is that a phone?

Comment: Click "copy to folder". Then select folder. Then just delete file.

Comment: @Gantendo the ftp server is a service on my phone to share my files so I can access them from my desktop whenever I'm at home on my wifi. If I connect with an ftp client such as WinSCP, its able to copy and paste files without any issue.

Comment: @Petepf, my ftp folder doesn't appear in the list of available folders in that picker.

Comment: And you can't share the folder on the phone via SMB?

Comment: Try drag file to top bar menu.